# Connecting to mysql database through socket from hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, sockets

I could not connect to mysql from java web application because I have created mysql database on user space. I think I have to pass socket file path also from configuration to connect to database. Please help me on connecting to mysql database through socket from hibernate.

### my.cnf

```
[server]
user=root
basedir=/installers/mysql
datadir=/installers/mysql/data
socket=/installers/mysql/socket
bind-address=xx.xx.xx.xx
pid-file=/installers/mysql/data.pid
tmpdir=/installers/mysql/tmp
port=3306
```

I able to login to mysql in following way

bin/mysql --socket=socket -u root -p

but I could not connect to mysql from java web application,

## db.properties

```
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/app
jdbc.username=root
jdbc.password=password
jdbc.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
```

## MVC config file

```
<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
    p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driver}" p:url="${jdbc.url}" p:username="${jdbc.username}"
    p:password="${jdbc.password}" />
```

## Exception

```
org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Cannot open connection
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:428)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:372)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:417)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:255)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at sun.proxy.$Proxy28.getPreviousDayData(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:440)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:428)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Cannot open connection
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1235)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1168)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.throwPersistenceException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1245)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:63)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.DefaultJpaDialect.beginTransaction(DefaultJpaDialect.java:71)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.beginTransaction(HibernateJpaDialect.java:61)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:378)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Cannot open connection
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:52)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:449)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.JDBCContext.connection(JDBCContext.java:142)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.begin(JDBCTransaction.java:85)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1463)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:60)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

Last packet sent to the server was 0 ms ago.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1074)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2103)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:718)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:302)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:282)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:579)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:190)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:173)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:164)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:153)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:119)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:446)
    ... 51 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:391)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:241)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:253)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:280)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2026)
```

Comment: what is in mysql logs? it looks looks like wrong mysql config. try to connect via mysql -uroot -p

Comment: I able to log in to mysql from command line like this bin/mysql --socket=socket -u root -p. Not able to log in when using hibernate

Comment: I could not login by using mysql -u root -p, because mysql is  installed in user space and connected to mysql via socket. Please let me know if any other way to pass socket info in hibernate configuration.

Comment: i see, but you able to login with socket file, but Hibrnate tried port. please show MySQL log file and try to connect from console via port and  not socket file

Comment: bin/mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Thanks olexii for closely following up on this, finally I found the way to pass socket property

### in db.properties

jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/app?socket=/mysql/socket

### in my.cnf

bind-address=localhost

Comment: jdbc:mysql://[host:port],[host:port].../[database] »
[?propertyName1][=propertyValue1][&propertyName2][=propertyValue2]...i passed socket property in url and it worked.

Comment: don't work on Mac with MAMP.